# as3 vertical level alignment

Tags: actionscript-3, game-physics

I'm creating a platformer game that involves horizontal and vertical level scrolling. The level is tile based, built out of an array. Everything aside from the character are children of a levelholder mc. My problem is the realignment of the levelholder after a jump. Originally the characters y value would be changed during a jump and then be aligned on top of the tile it lands on (loop through tiles, hittest, `mc.y=tile[i].y-mc.height`).

Now I'm making it so that the y value of the levelholder is changed instead, keeping the character centered and allowing vertically scrollable levels. How can I realign the levelholder after a tile hits the character?

Basic jump function called from an enter_frame function when the character is not hitting a tile:

```
function charJump():void 
{
    if (! charJumping) {
        charJumping = true;
        jumpSpeed = jumpSpeedLimit * -1;
        lvlHolder.y -=  jumpSpeed;
    } else {
        if (jumpSpeed < 0) {
            jumpSpeed *=  1 - jumpSpeedLimit / 160;
            if (jumpSpeed > -jumpSpeedLimit/5) {
                jumpSpeed *=  -1;
            }
        }

        if (jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit) {
            jumpSpeed *=  1 + jumpSpeedLimit / 50;
        }

        lvlHolder.y -=  jumpSpeed;

        for (var i:int = 0; i<blockHolder.numChildren; i++) {
            var hitBlock:MovieClip = MovieClip(blockHolder.getChildAt(i));
            var trueY = hitBlock.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));
            if (botBox.hitTestObject(hitBlock)) {
                if (jumpSpeed > 0 && charHolder.y<=trueY.y - (charHolder.getChildAt(0).height/2)) {
                    charJumping = false;
                    doubleJumping = false;
                    //lvlHolder.y = stage.stageHeight - lvlHolder.height;
                    charHolder.y = trueY.y - (charHolder.getBounds(this).y + charHolder.height - charHolder.y)+1;
                    charOnGround = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need clarification on your question: "how to realign the levelholder after a tile hits the character."  What's your implementation of the issue, and what are the factors?  There are many ways to code a solution; how to resolve your specific issue requires demonstration on how it's not working.  Try to boil your code down to a nuclear example, and you may find the solution while trying to share it online.

Comment: I included a basic version of my jump function so you can see what I'm talking about. Without any repositioning, the level will gradually decrease in y value (the level goes upward) as the player keeps jumping and eventually be offscreen. The commented out part was my first attempt at a solution, it repositions the level so that the bottom of it is at the bottom of the screen. This is not a good solution however because it doesnt allow vertical scrolling. Did this clarify the question a bit?